# Maven Mojo & SCM Plugin: Add file to ignore list / set SVN property

Tags: maven, svn, ignore, mojo, maven-scm

I'm using `maven-scm-plugin` from within an own Maven Mojo via an injected `ScmManager` object and am trying to figure out how to add a file to the SCM ignore list.

The methods that `ScmManager` provides don't seem to support this.

An ideal solution would work in all SCM systems that `maven-scm-plugin` supports. I'm not sure though if every system has such a feature. That said, a solution which only works with Subversion repositories would help me as well.

The corresponding SVN command would be something like

```
svn propset svn:ignore -F theFile .
```

If `ScmManager` cannot directly set ignore lists, maybe it has an ability to set these kind of SCM properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SCM Manager is an abstraction of more or less all version control tools so i think it would never offer such a functionality. But why do you need such a thing in Maven ? Maven is a build tool...Mabe you can create a separate stand-alone Maven Plugin to handle such things if you need for SVN only.

Comment: Well, the SCM Manager offers methods to check out, check in, update, branch, tag, changelog files, so setting SCM properties is, imho, not a long way off.

I need it for a POM preprocessor (I explained it a bit more in detail in the last comment to question [1]) to let the SCM system ignore the generated POM.

I guess there's no other way than to either leave it be or implement it myself. Is it possbile to issue custom commands with the SvnExeScmProvider?

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779003/maven-mojo-taking-complete-control-over-logging-forbid-other-plugins-to-log

Comment: The intention of the SCM Manager is to support Maven in its process (like release etc.) but not the usual checkout/checkin etc. task (In my opinion). My question is open: Why do you need such a thing and not using commandline or other integrations (IDE, TortoiseSVN whatever?)

Comment: Because my POM preprocessor is a Maven plugin and as such the use of the SCM Manager was very obvious and helpful so far. With it, I can check out or update files from SCM in a single line of code and get support for various SCM systems out of the box. I of course understand that it can only support the feature superset of all SCM systems. Nevertheless, I hoped it would be possible to do the ignore/propset stuff.